# to_date alternative for date of type character

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a table were the date required to be fetched is of type character. I tried using CONVERT function but it isn't working.
The query works fine in postgres but not in db2.

```
select * FROM abc 
where (to_date(from_month_year,'MM/YYYY') between '01/04/2017' and '01/04/2018') 
OR (to_date(to_month_year,'MM/YYYY')between '01/04/2017' and '01/04/2018') 
union 
select * FROM abc 
where ('01/04/2017' between to_date(from_month_year,'MM/YYYY') 
and to_date(to_month_year,'MM/YYYY')) 
OR ('01/04/2018' between to_date(from_month_year,'MM/YYYY') 
and to_date(to_month_year,'MM/YYYY'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use **Date Format** str_to_date.

`DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(StartDate,'%d-%m-%Y'), '%m-%Y')`